# Problem with rigging character and paint weight

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I've modeled this character and rigged with meta rig. As you can see on screenshot, my hand is pulling ear, beard and some other parts of head although paint weight is completely blue for all parts of hand rig[image]. I've had similar problem with jacket, but merging all by distance in Edit Mode solved problem with jacket. Can anyone help me with this problem. All parts of head all joined.

Answer (score 0):

Having a weight of zero doesn't mean a vertex won't move in response to a bone's movement. The vertex has to be removed from the corresponding vertex group of the bone to ensure it is not influenced by the bone. This only becomes an issue when the weighting of the model is still in-progress as vertices won't necessary have a non-zero weight to any of the bones. In your case, the head is probably still not skinned to the head bone.

In summary, you have two options:

1. Assign the head vertices to the head bone.
2. Remove the head vertices from the vertex groups of the arm bones.